# How to count the number of employees based on age groups in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, count

I have a problem with writing a code for employee count based on age groups. I have six age groups and would love to render out the total number of employees that falls in-between those ages.

For instance:

> Baby Boomers | 20 Employees
>
> Gen Y | 15 Employees

And so on...

Here is my #models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Employee(models.Model):
    # basic information of employee
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=40)
    middle_name = models.CharField(_('middle name'), max_length=40, default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=40)
    emp_photo = models.ImageField(_('passport'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(_('birthday'))
    gender = models.CharField(_('gender'), max_length=15, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    house_address = models.CharField(_('house address'), max_length=100)
    city_of_residence = models.CharField(_('city'), max_length=100)
    state_of_residence = models.CharField(_('state'), max_length=100, choices=NIGERIAN_STATE_CHOICES)
    country_of_residence = models.CharField(_('country'), max_length=100, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES,
                                            default=[156, 'Nigeria'])
    # employment record of employee
    emp_id = models.CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True, max_length=15, default="CLA190000")
    job_title = models.ForeignKey(JobTitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('job title'))
    dept_name = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('department'))
    branch_name = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('branch'))
    hired_date = models.DateField(_('hired date'))
    leave_days = models.IntegerField(_('leave days'), default=20)
    status = models.CharField(_('status'), choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Employee')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Employees')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Can someone please help me out with this? I would so much appreciate it if the code can work on both SQLite (development) and Postgres (production).

Thanks

Comment: if you already splited them in the database by a field or models you can just use count() function in the queries

Comment: Please add you model code.

Comment: Can you please add your models, and specify what the age groups are?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I have added the models

Comment: I do not see the age group field? How are you calculating the employees age group?

Comment: @MarcellErasmus: I think that is the `date_of_birth`...

Comment: If that is the case you will have to filter on `date_of_birth__range=[start_date, end_date]`. Unfortunately you will have to do multiple queries for each range.

Comment: Employees.objects.raw('SELECT COUNT(first_name) FROM table_name
WHERE condition')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group employees by age group with `.values`then count the objects by `id` with `annotation`. This will return the count of each group in a `queryset`.

```
from django.db.models import count

Employee.objects.values('age_group_field').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

If you have to filter on the `date_of_birth` you will have to use a range filter to get all employees falling in that age group.

```
# start_date and end_date are python date objects specified by you

baby_boomers = Employees.objects.filter(date_of_birth__range=[start_date, end_date]).count()
```

Comment: I tried this out and got a "TypeError at /
expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: `"employee_age_group": Employee.objects.values('date_of_birth').annotate(count=Count('emp_id'))`

Comment: @Marcell...I was able to group employees by age group just as you recommended, however, I encountered troubles when I tried to filter on the date of birth. My end goal is to use the filter to update my dashboard chart. That is not working.

Comment: Please look at the second part of my answer. You will not be able the use`.values` with a date field. But the date range filter should work

Comment: Oops! That was terrible of me. I forgot to add the object...Thank you @Marcell... I was able to sort it out all thanks to you and everyone else that contributed. I used the following line of code to filter `bb = Employee.objects.filter(date_of_birth__range=[datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 1)]).count()`

Answer (score 0):

You can Use sql query

```
 cat1 = Employees.objects.raw('SELECT COUNT(first_name) FROM table_name WHERE 
 condition')
```

You can specify the age condition as per as your requirement.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/